why does it always executing the else block of code?
I was trying to make an isNaN() function that checks the user's input if its a NaN or not, but it always skips the the first condition whatever the user's input is.
function isNaN() {
    let value = prompt("enter value");

    if (typeof value === "number") {
    console.log("value is number");
    }else {
    console.log("NaN");
    }
} isNaN();

I made the program to checks the user's input data type by typeof operator.

prompt() always returns a string or null. Even if the string looks numeric, the type is still string.

Use parseFloat() to try to convert the input to a number. It will return NaN if it can't parse it.

This would be a good time to learn to debug unexpected output. Also note that potentially overwriting the default isNaN() implementation, intentionally or not, is not a good idea.

Wouldn't it have been simple to just do console.log(typeof value) to see why the condition isn't working as expected?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Try this:
    let value = prompt("enter value");
    console.log("Value entered:" + value);
    console.log("Type of value: " + typeof value);

    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
    console.log("String contains a number");
    }else {
    console.log("NaN");
    }

